# How do I verify my LoadRunner test scripts are actually being executed?

Tags: performance, testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I've a requirement to load test a web application using loadRunner(Community edition : 12.53 ). Currently I've my test scripts recorded using loadrunner default test script recorder. I'm assuming that, the operations I chose to perform in SUT should actually update the application backend/DB when I'm executing the test scripts. Is this the correct behavior of a load testing scenario? 
When I ran my test scripts, I couldn't see any value or nothing updated in the application DB.

I've my test scripts written in C and also manual correlation is applied using web_reg_save_param method.

What might be the things that could go wrong in such a scenario?. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the operations I chose to perform in SUT should actually update the application backend/DB when I'm executing the test scripts. Is this the correct behavior of a load testing scenario?  - Yes this is the correct behaviour.

When I ran my test scripts, I couldn't see any value or nothing updated in the application DB. - Something you might be missing in the correlations. this generally happens when some variable is not correlated properly or gets missed. Or something like timestamp that you might think is irrelevant but needs to be taken care of.